# lottie animation not playing in different devices

Tags: android, animation, lottie

Hello everyone i have a problem with LottieAnimationView.
I taught how to use it but the problem is that it works in different devices i tested in the emulator and my phone

but in device (redmi note 4) Android 7 but does not work in Logcat there is such a message
this error logcat:

```
2020-04-02 08:20:35.693 5615-5615/com.example.askme E/status: getvalue
2020-04-02 08:20:35.717 5615-5615/com.example.askme E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
2020-04-02 08:20:35.717 5615-5615/com.example.askme E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
2020-04-02 08:20:35.717 5615-5615/com.example.askme E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
2020-04-02 08:20:35.717 5615-5615/com.example.askme E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
2020-04-02 08:20:35.717 5615-5615/com.example.askme E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
2020-04-02 08:20:35.717 5615-5615/com.example.askme E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
2020-04-02 08:20:35.866 5615-5615/com.example.askme E/status: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "yesno.wtf": No address associated with hostname
2020-04-02 08:20:35.992 5615-5615/com.example.askme E/status: end
```

this warning logcat:

```
2020-04-02 08:20:35.497 5615-5615/com.example.askme W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2020-04-02 08:20:35.651 5615-5651/com.example.askme W/LOTTIE: Animation contains merge paths. Merge paths are only supported on KitKat+ and must be manually enabled by calling enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove().
```

this my xml:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/mainlottie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove="true"
    app:lottie_fileName="circle.json"
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

this lottie version:

def lottieVersion = "3.3.1"
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

I searched the internet but found nothing
I will be very happy if you help

Comment: Any update on this?